# Setting up the multiprocessor capabilities of PyCharm

Tags: configuration, pycharm, preferences

PyCharm has the possibility to be configured to run a multithreaded (or multiprocess) Python program in the Preferences panel. However, I also know they recently changed the name to this configuration in this panel. I need to remember how to set this.

Can someone please tell me how? I have been looking in the PyCharm manual on their WEB page and simply cannot find it.

I am using PyCharm ver 2022.3 on Mac OS

I have been looking for help on PyCharm's web page and cannot find anything.